# When executing "bundle exec rails runner", how can I specify the application's directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, bundler

When I execute this command:

```
/usr/local/bin/bundle exec rails runner -e production "load 'job_alerta_validacao.rb'"
```

It returns:

```
Could not locate Gemfile
```

How can I set where the application is directly in the command without needing to create a script with the "cd" command?

Comment: What do you have against `cd`? Rails expects somewhat to be run from its root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to use bundler is to `cd` to the directory containing the Gemfile. This is also the most robust way, since some other gems will probably assume that the working directory is the root of the Rails project.

If you just don't want to change your current shell's working directory, `cd` in a subshell:

```
(cd /some/directory; /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rails runner -e production "load 'job_alerta_validacao.rb'")
```

If you really want to execute something through bundler with a working directory other than the directory with the Gemfile, tell bundler where to find the Gemfile with the BUNDLE_GEMFILE environment variable:

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/some/directory/Gemfile /usr/local/bin/bundle exec rails runner -e production "load 'job_alerta_validacao.rb'"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I used "BUNDLE_GEMFILE" method